# How to find the Domain of this function?

Tags: functions

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Log[10, x + a/x - 2]
FunctionDomain[{f[x], a > 0}, x] // Reduce[#, a] &
```

USE

```
In[22]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Log[10, x + a/x - 2]
FunctionDomain[{f[x], a > 0}, x] // Reduce[#, a] &
```

> Out[23]= Log[-2 + a/x + x]/Log[10]

> Out[24]= (0 < x <= 2 && a > 2 x - x^2) || (x > 2 && a > 0)

The answer above is incorrect

the correct answer is as follows:

> (0 < a <=
> 1 && (0 < x < 1 - Sqrt[1 - a] || x > 1 + Sqrt[1 - a])) || (a > 1 &&
> x > 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FunctionDomain[{Log[10, x + a/x - 2], a > 0}, x]// Reduce[#, x] &
(*(0 < a <=1 && (0 < x < 1 - Sqrt[1 - a] || x > 1 + Sqrt[1 - a])) || (a > 1&&x > 0)*)
```

gives the "correct asnwer".

By the way `RegionPlot[...]` shows no difference between the two conditions `// Reduce[#, a] &` and `// Reduce[#, x] &` !

Comment: if the two domains are given by `{fd1, fd2}` then `{rgn1, rgn2} = ImplicitRegion[#, {a, x}] & /@ {fd1, fd2};` and `RegionEqual[rgn1, rgn2]` evaluates to `True`